# What should I back up in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: coldfusion, backup

**What should we back up within ColdFusion 9?**

We are backing up the websites and the databases, but what should we back up within ColdFusion Administrator?  I am concerned with the Data Sources, Web Services etc...

Any best practices / pit falls we should be aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backup the following:

- any XML files in the /lib directory. This might be buried down in the /jrun4/servers directory on a multi-instance install, or it might be in cfusion9/lib. The XML files all begin with "neo-" and contain your settings.
- Jrun.XML and Web.xml
- Any custom tags in the various customtag directories.
- Any CFX tags
- Any third party jar files you might be using.
- The keystore file in the java security directory

Where all these things live greatly depends on your install. There's quite a bit of variety in the way you can run CF on a given platform. The tips above apply to CF 9 and below. CF 10 will have some similarity but things are in very different places.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to grab a copy of the Settings Summary in the CFAdmin. Pulling that information periodically has saved my butt when "but nothing has changed!" errors start occurring. I kind of wish CF had a way of automatically making a history of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a coldfusion archive.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fc5.html